# How to change a Text of a TextLabel for a Attribute of the player

Tags: lua, roblox, luau

I need to change a TextLabel text to a Player Attribute Value but i dont know how to do this.
I tried to make a code:

```
local player = game.Players.LocalPlayer
function ChangeTextMastery()
    script.Parent.Frame.CurrentMastery.Text = "Current Mastery - " .. tonumber(player:GetAttribute("Mastery"))
end

game.Players.PlayerAdded:Connect(ChangeTextMastery)
```

Answer (score 0):

try changing tonumber() to a tostring()

Answer (score -1):

Yes you must do tostring() because it only accepts strings and not integers. If you want you can also write tostring(tonumber(Player:GetAttribute("Mastery"))) but I do not think it is needed